# How can i tune autovacuum configs for pg toast tables?

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

I have a pg_toast table which has a lot of dead tuples accumulating. The autovacuum job on it runs for a very long time.
I wanted to tune the autovacuum config, to make it more aggressive.

When i'm trying to set the config I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  permission denied: "pg_toast_16432" is a system catalog
```

Query used:

```
ALTER TABLE pg_toast.pg_toast_16432 SET (autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0);
```

Postgres version: 11

Can someone please suggest how to tune autoconfig on toast tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a storage parameter on the table itself, as described in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-STORAGE-PARAMETERS). If the table is called `tab`, run

```
ALTER TABLE tab SET (toast.autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 0);
```

Note that setting `autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor` to 0 won't do what you want. To speed up autovacuum, increase `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit` or reduce `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly modify the autovacuum configuration for individual system catalog tables, however, you can consider using other performance optimization techniques like indexing and query optimization to reduce the need for aggressive autovacuuming.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).